# Irfanview cli command pauses batch file

Tags: batch-file, irfanview

I have a batch file that runs in hidden mode using the CHP utility - no problem with that, but I'd like to have a little indicator that the script is running. Here's how I've tried to do it -

```
"c:\Program Files\irfanview\i_view32.exe" h:\rippers\scripts\0020.gif /hide=15
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "/home/paul/scripts/sqlite/syncsqlremoterip7b.sh"
"c:\Program Files\irfanview\i_view32.exe" /killmesoftly
```

This script should present an animate gif of an hourglass while the main command (line 2) runs - the hourglass is removed by line 3.

The problem is the script pauses at the end of line 1, and the only way to get the script to continue is to manually close irfanview - which defeats the point.

Any thoughts on how to resolve, or alternative ways to achieve what I want are welcome.

Comment: have you tried `start "" "c:\.......exe" ...`?

Comment: That's the answer I think - at least it works on a test file. Thanks